# Consume soap web service from excel

Tags: java, excel

I have  created a JAVA Soap web service that inserts data into mysql using JDBC. i want to modify it so that it inserts data into a Excel table instead of mysql. Can someone please give  a in depth description as to how i can do it. I do not know how to use excel. So i expect a clear explanation

Comment: apache poi is good option.

Answer (score 0):

Excel table isn't a data structure, its a software.
You could build a file in a form that excel respects, like xml or csv, 
and opening the file using ms-excel.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/writingDom.html